# Sum up in group by query on single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, count, group-by

I have a task model with attributes like created_at, hours and different states that i want to show aggregated by month and sum up the different states.

```
| Month   | Count | Hours | States
| 2012-01 | 22    | 26.5  | new(3), closed(4), others(15)
| 2012-02 | 12    | 16.5  | new(0), approved(2), closed(9), others(1)
...
```

Currently I am using this query which groups by month and gives me count + hours.

```
@tasks = Task.select("date(created_at), count(id), sum(hours) AS hours")
             .group("MONTH(created_at)") 
             .order('created_at')
```

How can i add a sum on all different states?

I have read about group_by but i do not think that this is good with a lot of results.

**Update**

With a query like this i got nearly what i want.

```
@tasks = Tasks.select("date(created_at), state, count(state), sum(hours) AS hours")
          .group("MONTH(created_at)") 
          .group("state")
          .order('created_at')

| Month   | Count | Hours | State
| 2012-01 | 3     | 26.5  | new
| 2012-01 | 4     | 16.5  | approved
| 2012-01 | 15    | 22.5  | others
| 2012-02 | 2     | 16.5  | approved
| 2012-02 | 9     | 16.5  | closed
...
```

**Update2**

I have an sql query that gives me the result i need.

```
@tasks = Task.select("
  DATE( created_at ) AS month, 
  COUNT( state ), 
  SUM( hours ) AS hours,
  COUNT( case when `state` = 'new' then `state` else NULL end ) AS state_new,
  SUM( case when `state` = 'new' then `hours` else NULL end ) AS state_new_hours,
  COUNT( case when `state` = 'approved' then `state` else NULL end ) AS state_approved,
  SUM( case when `state` = 'approved' then `hours` else NULL end ) AS state_approved_hours,
  COUNT( case when `state` = 'closed' then `state` else NULL end ) AS state_closed,
  SUM( case when `state` = 'closed' then `hours` else NULL end ) AS state_closed_hours,
  COUNT( case when `state` != 'new' AND `state` != 'approved' AND `state` != 'closed' then `state` else NULL end ) AS state_misc")
.group("MONTH(created_at)") 
.order('created_at')
```

Can this be done through a join? How todo this in a more common rails way and have dynamic state usage?

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of states - so only 'new', 'closed', 'others' possible, or are they subject to grow?

Comment: its possible to get new states but then i know about them. so some kind of fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm assuming you're using MySQL and that you have a seperate `states` table and the states in the other columns are referenced by ID, like so:

```
| ID | Name   |
| 1  | new    |
| 2  | closed |
| 3  | open   |
```

So by executing this SQL statement in MySQL

```
SELECT states.name AS state, DATE_FORMAT(tasks.created_at, '%Y-%m') AS month,
       COUNT(tasks.id) AS count, SUM(tasks.hours) AS hours
  FROM states JOIN tasks ON states.id = tasks.state_id
GROUP BY state, month
ORDER BY month
```

you should get a result like this

```
| state  | month   | count | hours |
| open   | 2012-03 | 22    | 38.5  |
| open   | 2012-04 | 17    | 40.0  |
| closed | 2012-03 | 45    | 0.5   |
```

So, you just need to bring this query to an ActiveRelation query, or you could use `Task.find_by_sql`.
It's not the exact same way you described how you want your result to look, but with this set you can alter it using plain ruby, after executing...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My states are in the same table like the tasks. I have updated my question and added another query that does nearly what i want.